# Device and connection in Network Manger?

Tags: network-manager, configuration, connection

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 machine and using **Network Manager** as the service for managing network configurations.

What is the difference between a **Device** and **Connection** in Network Manager?

Also what are the specific properties of both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are different entities that work together to manage your network configuration.

A device is a physical or virtual network interface, such as an Ethernet card, Wi-Fi adapter, or VPN interface

A Connection is a set of configuration settings that define how a Device should connect to a specific network. Connections are stored as reusable, modifiable profiles.